# Read a Text/CSV file from an SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle, text-files, toad

I wish to use an external Text/CSV file to read data and run an SQL Query. Is this possible without using the External_Table concept? I do not have write permissions in the DB, hence cannot create a temp table in the DB.

Basically, I have a list of employee numbers (around 100) in a text file, using which I wish to run the following query each time:

```
SELECT emp_record FROM emp_data WHERE emp_no = "@file-containing-number"
```

I have to run a series of tasks on these and they are in no particular order or sequence, but have been provided in that text file as a list.

I am using the TOAD client and have only read-only permissions on the DB I connect to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I do this sort of thing I will open the file in notepad, add a comma to the end of each line and use the following SQL query:

```
select emp_record FROM emp_data WHERE emp_no IN (

... Paste contents of file here.

)
```

Answer (score 1):

No - based on the limitations you mention in your question.

Are you saying you cannot even insert these records into a table in the database?  Who is imposing these restrictions?  You have a job to do.  Other support staff should help in providing a means to accomplish the job.